# Java webdriver modifying html element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
 <span data-id="tag-dist-Porto" title="Para eliminar uma das opções, faça duplo clique."></span>
```

This is the element I'm trying to modify using webdriver.

This is my code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();


    driver.get("The url");


    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-id='tag-dist-Porto']"));



    element.sendKeys("Random String");


    element.submit()
```

I can't figure out what is going on...

After trying your javaExecutor solutions I got these errors:

```
xception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:     com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException:      ReferenceError:"bysideWebcare_detectWindowScroll" is not defined.     (http://webcare.byside.com/agent/byside_webcare.js#20)
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'PT-PC0E5041', ip: '10.123.206.3', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:530)
    at testestestes.Example.main(Example.java:28)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError:      "bysideWebcare_detectWindowScroll" is not defined.      (http://webcare.byside.com/agent/byside_webcare.js#20)
    at .....
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-id='tag-dist-Porto']"))` doesen't work! The programm doesn't reach any further than that. If fails when it executes that line of code, returning the error above.

Answer (score 0):

sendKeys only works for editable elements like TextBox, Rich edit boxes etc. You can write something to a

or a  tag.

Comment: This is a text box and the problem that this program fails before reaching that part. It can't find the element..

Comment: <span> are not textboxes. Do you have an example that we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what web element it is associated with this span tag, you can't send keys using selenium webDriver.
you can try action classes of selenium if that works for you:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Actions seriesOfActions = builder.moveToElement(element).click().sendKeys(element, "test text");
        seriesOfActions.perform();
```

Also you can try Javascript but this is only if you want to send keys and that is the only and solely action you want to perform

```
1. document.getElementsByTagName('span')[index].value="test text"
2. document.getElementsByTagName('span')[index].innerHTML="test text"
```

Try them on console of the browser before coding.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `sendKeys()` method for `<span>` which is not possible.

you can use `sendKeys()` for sending value in `input`, `textarea` like tags or sending keyboard keys.

You will be able to change `span` tag value by using `JavascriptExecuter` in selenium. Refer following code -

```
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 'Your_Text_Here';");
```

OR

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-id='tag-dist-Porto']"));
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = 'Your Text Here'", element);
```